# Array and For loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have

```
$arr=array(array(1,2,3),
           array(4,5,6),
           array(7,8,9),
           array(10,11,12))
```

I need to display it in this order using for loop: 1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11,3,6,9,12.
I have been busting my head for last two days on this, can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Are the inner arrays of the same length (always 3)? Also, you should share what you tried.

Comment: Yes they are always the same length. I have been trying something like this      `for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    for($u = 0; $u <count($arr[$i]); $j++) {
        echo $arr[$i][$u];
        echo '<br />';
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple solution apply to use non-predefined length of the main array and its child:

```
$arr=array(array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array(10,11,12));

$count_arr = count($arr);       // length of the main array
$count_arr_arr = count($arr[0]);// length of the child array (each child should be the same length)
$res_arr = [];

for($i = 0; $i < $count_arr_arr; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < $count_arr; $j++){
        $res_arr[] = $arr[$j][$i];        // getting elements from child arrays 
    } 
}

echo join(', ', $res_arr);                // presenting the result as a string '1, 2, 3, etc.'
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c56ea73bd9a82da00137c271810ab6215afdce5)

Answer (score 1):

Something like following might help

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
        echo $arr[$j][$i];
    }
}
```

You effectively cycle through 3 columns (`$i`) and 4 rows (`$j`) and reference the appropriate `$arr` elements.

If you wanted to use a more dynamic (count) based solution, you would use e.g:

```
$count = count($arr);

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
        echo $arr[$j][$i];
    }
}
```

[updated demo](https://3v4l.org/d2YGa)

note: *it is more efficient to `count()` outside the `for` loop, so you only call the function once and use the result inside the loop.*

Comment: How can that be done with `count($arr)` in case i want to add some more information in those arrays later on?

Comment: @lovelace Your edit isn't right. `$arr` corresponds to the `$j` index in this case. Should just be `for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop nesting for that. So iterate through the array and increase the index of the column on each outer loop. Store the values in a new array for proper output.

```
$arr=array(array(1,2,3),
array(4,5,6),
array(7,8,9),
array(10,11,12));

$new = [];
$i = 0;

foreach($arr as $set) {
    foreach($arr as $data) {
        if(isset($data[$i])) $new[] = $data[$i];
    }
    $i++;
}

echo join(',', $new), PHP_EOL;
```

> 1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11,3,6,9,12